# Sending raw JSON to GraphQL mutation

Tags: json, graphql, graphql-java

I need to upload through a GraphQL mutation an object whose schema is not known at design time. Basically it is a raw JSON blob that may or may not come from other, possibly non-GraphQL services. I am using JSON scalar from https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars:

```
scalar JSON

input MyInput {
  jsonField: JSON
}
```

It works nicely except when the input blob contains keys like "$ref", which is the standard way to describe references in JSON. However, field name `$ref` does not seem to be accepted as it does not conform to the GraphQL naming conventions.

Obvious solutions appear to be to encode-decode field names in some way, or send the whole JSON as a String, perhaps with a custom scalar type. But is there perhaps a more elegant way to achieve this?